# Solving a complex integral by parametrization and geometric series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have to solve the given integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z}+e^{z^2}dz \ \ \ \ \ where\ \ \gamma(t)=e^{-it} \ on  \ t=[0,4\pi]
\end{equation}

Since the first part is rapidly solved by parametrization, and the second is more difficult, I do the following on the first term (setting $z=e^{-it},\ \  dz=-ie^{-it}dt$):

\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z}dz=-\int_0^{4\pi}\frac{1}{e^{-it}}ie^{-it}dt=-it\mid_0^{4\pi}=-4i\pi
\end{equation}

The second however, I solve by writing $e^z\ ^{2}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{(2+n)}$:

\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma e^{z^2}dz = \frac{1}{n!}\int_\gamma \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z^2)^n dz=\frac{1}{n!}\int_\gamma \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2+n} dz
\end{equation}

which gives  by parameterizing $z=e^{-it}\ ,\ dz=-ie^{-it}dt$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n!}\int_\gamma \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2+n} dz=-\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{4\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ie^{-it(2+n)}e^{-it}dt= -\frac{i}{n!}\int_0^{4\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-it(3+n)}dt=-\frac{i}{n!}\int_0^{4\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-it(3+n)}dt
\end{equation}

which gives

\begin{equation}
-\frac{i}{n!}\int_0^{4\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-it(3+n)}dt=-\frac{1}{n!(3+n)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-it(3+n)}\mid_0^{4\pi}=-\frac{1}{(n+3)n!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(e^{-12i\pi(3+n)}-e^0\bigg)
\end{equation}

which results in:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{(n+3)n!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(e^{-12i\pi(3+n)}-e^0\bigg)=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1 + e^{-4 i π(3 + n)}(3 + n))}{n!}
\end{equation}

Taking the limit of this:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}-\frac{(-1 + e^{-4 i π(3 + n)}(3 + n))}{n!}=0
\end{equation}

So going back to the original form:

\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z}+e^{z^2}dz = -4\pi i +0 =-4\pi i 
\end{equation}

Would this be a correct approach to the original complex integral?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{z^2}$ is a holomorphic function. So, the integral along the closed curve $=0$.

Your approach for the first part is okay. But, by recognizing the curve is $|z|=1$ oriented clockwise for two rotations, you can immediately obtain $-4\pi i$ without calculation.

Comment: How do you see that a function in holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Both $e^z$ and $z^2$ are holomorphic. So, the composite of them is also holomorphic.

Comment: What about $e^{i2}$?

Comment: Is it $2$ or $z$? Anyway, they are both holomorphic.

Comment: It is 2, and since holomorphic is differentiable, I would have then deduced that also $x^{2i}$ would be holomorphic?

Comment: No. What made you think so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132636/discussion-between-viola-player-and-i-h).